# C Linux Bandwidth Throttling of Application

Tags: c, linux, throttling

What are some ways I can try to throttle back a `send`/`sendto()` function inside a loop. I am creating a port scanner for my network and I tried two methods but they only seem to work locally (they work when I test them on my home machine but when I try to test them on another machine it doesn't want to create appropriate throttles).

### method 1

I was originally parsing `/proc/net/dev` and reading in the "bytes sent" attribute and basing my sleep time off that. That worked locally (the sleep delay was adjusting to adjust the flow of bandwidth) but as soon as I tried it on another server also with `/proc/net/dev` it didn't seem to be adjusting data right. I ran `dstat` on a machine I was locally scanning and it was outputting to much data to fast.

### method 2

I then tried to keep track of how many bytes total I was sending and adding it to a `total_sent` variable which my bandwidth thread would read and compute a sleep timer for. This also worked on my local machine but when I tried it on a server it was saying that it was only sending 1-2 packets each time my bandwidth thread would check `total_sent` making my bandwidth thread reduce sleep to 0, but even at 0 the `total_sent` variable did not increase due to the reduced sleep time but instead stayed the same.

Overall I am wanting a way to monitor bandwidth of the Linux computer and calculate a sleep time I can pass into `usleep()` before or after each of my `send`/`sendto()` socket calls to throttle back the bandwidth.

**Edit:** some other things I forgot to mention is that I do have a speedtest function that calculates upload speed of the machine and I have 2 threads. 1 thread adjusts a global sleep timer based on bandwidth usage and thread 2 sends the packets to the ports on a remote machine to test if they are open and to fingerprint them (right now I am just using udp packets with a `sendto()` to test this all).

How can I implement bandwidth throttling for a `send`/`sendto()` call using `usleep()`.

**Edit:** Here is the code for my bandwidth monitoring thread. Don't concern yourself about the structure stuff, its just my way of passing data to a thread.

```
void *bandwidthmonitor_cmd(void *param)
{
  int i = 0;
  double prevbytes = 0, elapsedbytes = 0, byteusage = 0, maxthrottle = 0;

  //recreating my param struct i passed to the thread
  command_struct bandwidth = *((command_struct *)param);
  free(param);

  //set SLEEP (global variable) to a base time in case it was edited and not reset
  SLEEP = 5000;

  //find the maximum throttle speed in kb/s (takes the global var UPLOAD_SPEED
  //which is in kb/s and times it by how much bandwidth % you want to use
  //and devides by 100 to find the maximum in kb/s
  //ex: UPLOAD_SPEED = 60, throttle = 90, maxthrottle = 54
  maxthrottle = (UPLOAD_SPEED * bandwidth.throttle) / 100;
  printf("max throttle: %.1f\n", maxthrottle);

  while(1)
  {
      //find out how many bytes elapsed since last polling of the thread
      elapsedbytes = TOTAL_BYTES_SEND - prevbytes;
      printf("elapsedbytes: %.1f\n", elapsedbytes);

      //set prevbytes to our current bytes so we can have results next loop
      prevbytes = TOTAL_BYTES_SEND;

      //convert our bytes to kb/s
      byteusage = 8 * (elapsedbytes / 1024);

      //throttle control to make it adjust sleep 20 times every 30~ 
      //iterations of the loop
      if(i & 0x40)
      {
           //adjust SLEEP by 1.1 gain
           SLEEP += (maxthrottle - byteusage) * -1.1;//;


           if(SLEEP < 0){
               SLEEP = 0;
           }
           printf("sleep:%.1f\n\n", SLEEP);
      }

      //sleep the thread for a short bit then start the process over
      usleep(25000);
      //increment variable i for our iteration throttling
      i++;
  }

}
```

My sending thread is just a simple `sendto()` routine in a `while(1)` loop sending udp packets for testing. `sock` is my `sockfd`, `buff` is a 64 byte character array filled with "A" and `sin` is `my sockaddr_in`.

```
  while(1)
  {
    TOTAL_BYTES_SEND += 64;

    sendto(sock, buff, strlen(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin))


    usleep(SLEEP);
  }
```

I know my socket functions work because I can see the usage in `dstat` on my local machine and the remote machine. This bandwidth code works on my local system (all the variables change as they should) but on the server I tried testing on elapsed bytes does not change (is always 64/128 per iteration of the thread) and results in `SLEEP` throttling down to 0 which should in theory make the machine send packets faster but even with `SLEEP` equating to 0 elapsedbytes remain 64/128. I've also encoded the `sendto()` function inside a if statement checking for the function returning -1 and alerting me by `printf`-ing the error code but there hasn't been one in the tests I've done.

Comment: “I then tried to keep track of how many bytes total i was sending and adding it to a total_sent variable which my bandwidth thread would read and compute a sleep timer for.” — this sounds right to me, please post your code that attempts to do this.

Comment: @AlexeyFeldgendler: i posed some of my code. may this be a mutex locking issue? i am reading and writing to the same variable really fast from 2 threads without any locking.

Comment: as a test i changed my sendto line to `if((TOTAL_BYTES_SEND += sockto(sock,...)) == -1) { printf("error"); }` and there are no errors and i now get real output of the sendto() function, but of a server i own with 4000kb/s upload im still getting really low elapsedbytes which causes the SLEEP to become 0 which does not increase elapsedbytes as it does on my server (sleep throttles up and down to maintain a kb/s calculated as maxthrottle)

Comment: You should divide elapsedbytes by the time elapsed since last measurement. Otherwise what you get is some random number of bytes sent (within an unspecified interval), which is not directly comparable with maxthrottle (in kb/s).

Also, this code is ridden with race conditions. You should use a mutex to synchronize access to shared variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this could be most directly solved by calculating the throttle sleep time in the send thread.  I'm not sure I see the benefit of another thread to do this work.

Here is one way to do this:

Select a time window in which you will measure your send rate.  Based on your target bandwidth this will give you a byte maximum for that amount of time.  You can then check to see if you have sent that many bytes after each sendto().  If you do exceed the byte threshold then sleep until the end of the window in order to perform the throttling.

Here is some untested code showing the idea.  Sorry that clock_gettime and struct timespec add some complexity.  Google has some nice code snippets for doing more complete comparisons, addition, and subtraction with struct timespec.

```
#define MAX_BYTES_PER_SECOND (128L * 1024L)
#define TIME_WINDOW_MS 50L
#define MAX_BYTES_PER_WINDOW ((MAX_BYTES_PER_SECOND * TIME_WINDOW_MS) / 1000L)

#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(void) {
  struct timespec window_start_time;

  size_t bytes_sent_in_window = 0;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &window_start_time);

  while (1) {
    size_t bytes_sent = sendto(sock, buff, strlen(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin));
    if (bytes_sent < 0) {
      // error handling
    } else {
      bytes_sent_in_window += bytes_sent;

      if (bytes_sent_in_window >= MAX_BYTES_PER_WINDOW) {
        struct timespec now;
        struct timespec thresh;

        // Calculate the end of the window
        thresh.tv_sec = window_start_time.tv_sec;
        thresh.tv_nsec = window_start_time.tv_nsec;
        thresh.tv_nsec += TIME_WINDOW_MS * 1000000;
        if (thresh.tv_nsec > 1000000000L) {
          thresh.tv_sec += 1;
          thresh.tv_nsec -= 1000000000L;
        }

        // get the current time
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);

        // if we have not gotten to the end of the window yet
        if (now.tv_sec < thresh.tv_sec ||
            (now.tv_sec == thresh.tv_sec && now.tv_nsec < thresh.tv_nsec)) {

          struct timespec remaining;

          // calculate the time remaining in the window
          //  - See google for more complete timespec subtract algorithm
          remaining.tv_sec = thresh.tv_sec - now.tv_sec;
          if (thresh.tv_nsec >= now.tv_nsec) {
            remaining.tv_nsec = thresh.tv_nsec - now.tv_nsec;
          } else {
            remaining.tv_nsec = 1000000000L + thresh.tv_nsec - now.tv_nsec;
            remaining.tv_sec -= 1;
          }

          // Sleep to end of window
          nanosleep(&remaining, NULL);
        }

        // Reset counters and timestamp for next window
        bytes_sent_in_window = 0;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &window_start_time);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: silly question on my behalf but what would i need to change to make it throttle based on how much % of the total bandwidth i want to use? id assume the TIME_WINDOW_MS is the variable but i dont quite get how i can modify it to do what i need. also is the -lrt linker library standard to most linux machines? if not would i be able to use `struct timeval` instead?

Comment: thanks allot. this method is actually throttling the bandwidth back. i just do not know how to convert TIME_WINDOW_MS into a time which resembles a percentage of the total allowed bandwidth.

Comment: i cant edit my last two comments but ive tried editing MAX_BYTES_PER_SECOND to equate to a throttled back bandwidth speed `mbps = ((60 * 10) / 100) * 1024` which should equate to 6kb/s or 6144 bytes, but it doesnt seem to throttle the connection back at all. what does seem to throttle the connection though is modifying the TIME_WINDOW_MS value and increasing it up somewhere to 1 second (1000000). do i have to create some sort if gain for the TIME_WINDOW_MS variable to increase it until bytes being sent equals my estimated throttled bandwidth or should modifying max bytes per window be enough?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  MAX_BYTES_PER_SECOND is the target bandwidth in absolute terms.  In the code I posted its 128KB.  To do a percentage of available bandwidth you must define your maximum.  There is no way for the code to detect this.  You can then take the ratio of the target to the maximum to determine the percentage.  You can of course change the variables around to set percentage and max to then calculate the target.  So something like `#define MAX_BYTES_PER_SECOND (TARGET_PERCENT * TOTAL_AVAIL_BYTES_PER_SECOND)`.

Comment: Also, note that I had a bug in the way I calculated the end of window time.  I was multiplying by 1000 instead of 1000000 to convert from milliseconds to nanoseconds.  I don't know if you caught that, but it would throw off the algorithm quite a bit.  Hope that helps.

Comment: i fixed that error that you mentioned about the window end time. what im experiencing is that if i leave the `time_window_ms` at 50, no matter what i adjust the `max_bytes_per_second` to it always sends more data then it should. to try to fix this i set `time_window_ms` to 1000 (1 second) and then included a debug statement above `bytes_sent_in_window = 0` to print out that variable. after the change its sending the correct number of maximum bytes per second per window (each window is 1 second). is this one way to fix this code or is there a deeper seeded problem here?

Comment: How much over are you going?  A few bytes or much more?  If its just a few bytes over you could move the check for exceeding MAX_BYTES_PER_SECOND to before sendto() instead of after.  You just need to pre-calculate the expected number of bytes sent instead of using the return value from sendto().

Comment: Also, what other values of TIME_WINDOW_MS have you tried?  Keep in mind that while clock_gettime() and nanosleep() like to talk about nanosecond precision, you don't really get that from the operating system.  The 50ms may be too small for the system you are on.  I would think 250ms should give enough ticks on most modern platforms, though.  The window size is really a tunable you need to choose based on how precise you need to be vs. how bursty the traffic.  With a large window you will get better target bandwidth overall, but will tend to burst traffic and then pause, etc.

Comment: with max_bytes_per second equaling 54000 (54kb/s) and a time_window_ms of 50 before the bytes_sent_in_window is reset it equals 1080040. changing time_window_ms to 250 bytes_sent_in_window equals 216060 before its reset. changing time_window_ms to 500 makes bytes_sent_in_window 108030.  changing time_window_ms to 1000 bytes_sent_in_window becomes 54015 aka the target bytes i want to use per second.

Comment: Oh, sorry!  I have another stupid time conversion bug in there.  The MAX_BYTES_PER_WINDOW macro should use `TIME_WINDOW_MS / 1000` instead of `1000 / TIME_WINDOW_MS`.  I'll update the code above to reflect.  Note, you may get some whacky truncation errors since we're doing integer math.  You can switch to using floating point if that causes problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for a working solution. You've been a great help to me. Everything is now working as intended.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to do this at the application level, you could use a utility such as [trickle](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/control-your-bandwidth-trickle) to limit or shape the socket transfer rates available to the application.

For instance,

```
trickle -s -d 50 -w 100 firefox
```

would start `firefox` with a max download rate of 50KB/s and a peak detection window of 100KB. Changing these values may produce something suitable for your application testing.

Comment: id hate to have to install trickle on every machine i want to run my application on, thats why im trying to do this programmically. although this could be usefull for base testing to see if my throttle matches trickles throttle. thanks for this.