# Timers and Sleep on windows

Tags: c, windows, bandwidth, throttling

I am trying to port some linux code that uses `nanosleep()` and `get_clocktime()` to windows. As far as I have read there really isn't that many performance timers on windows and there are no real sleep functions other than `Sleep()`. I found `QueryPerformanceCounter` and `QueryPerformanceFrequency` on windows, but how would I adapt those to use with a fast sleep function. The code in which I am trying to port is located at this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13559213/1161270

Overall I'm trying to port linux code to windows that uses `nanosleep()`, `get_clocktime()` and `struct timespec`, but there seems to be no real equivalent. I am also open to other ideas on how to add throttle delays. I've read into the `PdhGetFormattedCounterArray()` functions and I have working code to monitor the output bandwidth of the computer in bytes, but I am unsure on how to use this data to create a delay to throttle back data sending to a specific kb/s speed, and would much rather use the other method provided in the linked post.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: can you ping to NUL for a time delay?

Comment: I am looking for a high frequency timing/sleeping solution. ping will not work, after all `Sleep()` which is calculated in milliseconds does not work for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Have you tried using Sleep?  Unless you're working with a gigabit network, a millisecond is less than a dozen normal-sized packets, so I'm not convinced that you really need ultra-fine resolution.  After all, you don't have all that much control over when the packets are actually sent, they might wind up being buffered up and sent in groups.  The other option would be to busy-wait, using the performance counters to work out the elapsed time, but you're still going to get erratic gaps whenever your thread is switched out.

Comment: Yes I have tried porting this code using `stuct timeval` and a ported version of `get_clocktime()` (that uses `QueryPerformanceCounter`) along with Sleep. It wasnt the behavior I expected. I also tried setting manual delays and it seems that if I set `Sleep(10)` I get about 30kb/s output but when I set `Sleep(5)` I get almost over 2mb/s according to my bandwidth monitors(why i assumed i need nanospeep etc) (my connection only uploads at 60kb/s). I've also noticed the grouping of packets in the performance counter logs. Could you give a better explanation of the busy-wait method you suggested?

Comment: Well, you can't use a constant sleep, obviously.  I note that the code you reference already has a window of 50 milliseconds, so the sleep is typically going to be on that order.  All you need to do is change the calculation to work out the number of milliseconds to sleep (instead of the number of nanoseconds) and then you can use Sleep.

Comment: Busy-wait is trivial, you just repeatedly check the time in a loop, without sleeping.  When you've reached the time you want, exit the loop.  I don't think the precision will be very much better than using Sleep, and I doubt you need it to be all that precise in the first place, but this is at least a very simple method.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that the ACTUAL precision on most OS's types of sleeps are often in milliseconds (or even some multiple thereof). It may well appear that you can sleep shorter periods, but in reality, either the OS doesn't actually put the process to sleep, or the sleep period is "ticks". This is true for both Linux (depending on kernel configuration) and Windows.

Microsoft explains timeouts here (and Sleep is simply a timeout waiting for nothing to happen):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#waitfunctionsandtime-outintervals

Comment: That's not true on Linux - with a modern kernel compiled with "NOHZ" enabled (which requires a modern CPU with a high precision timer), sleeps a with a granularity in the tens of microseconds are very achievable.