# Alternative to `tc` command or any api with `tc` functionality

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, network-programming

I want to shape the traffic or control bandwidth in my Linux machine. But I couldn't find any API related to functionality of `tc` command in Linux. As you would have guessed I am trying to use APIs' instead of commands.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557858/c-linux-bandwidth-throttling-of-application) is related, solution uses sleep/timers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tc` calls netlink to communicate with the kernel, here are some resources:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html
http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netlink

And there is also a library:

http://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/